# Best way to make a shell script daemon?

Tags: bash, shell, daemon

I'm wondering if there is a better way to make a daemon that waits for something using only sh than:

```
#! /bin/sh
trap processUserSig SIGUSR1
processUserSig() {
  echo "doing stuff"
}

while true; do
  sleep 1000
done
```

In particular, I'm wondering if there's any way to get rid of the loop and still have the thing listen for the signals.

Comment: You will need a loop, but note that your example is probably not going to perform in the way that you expect. The sleep is not a shell builtin, and a SIGUSR1 received by the shell is not propagated to child processes. Thus your signal handler will not get processed until the sleep is finished. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#preview, the 3rd section.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use your system's daemon facility, such as [start-stop-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html).

Otherwise, yes, there has to be a loop somewhere.

Comment: start-stop-daemon was surprisingly convenient to use

Answer (score 138):

Just backgrounding your script (`./myscript &`) will not daemonize it. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/, section 1.7, which describes what's necessary to become a daemon. You must disconnect it from the terminal so that `SIGHUP` does not kill it. You can take a shortcut to make a script appear to act like a daemon;

```
nohup ./myscript 0<&- &>/dev/null &
```

will do the job. Or, to capture both stderr and stdout to a file:

```
nohup ./myscript 0<&- &> my.admin.log.file &
```

Redirection explained (see [bash redirection](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial))

- `0<&-` closes stdin
- `&> file` sends stdout and stderr to a file

However, there may be further important aspects that you need to consider. For example:

- You will still have a file descriptor open to the script, which means that the directory it's mounted in would be unmountable. To be a true daemon you should `chdir("/")` (or `cd /` inside your script), and fork so that the parent exits, and thus the original descriptor is closed.
- Perhaps run `umask 0`. You may not want to depend on the umask of the caller of the daemon.

For an example of a script that takes all of these aspects into account, see [Mike S' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/best-way-to-make-a-shell-script-daemon/29107686#29107686).

Comment: First, thanks for this answer. It is mostly working very well for me. BUT I'd like to append to the log file and when I try "&>> log.txt" I get this error... "syntax error near unexpected token `>'" any ideas for me?

Comment: What does `0<&-` do? It's not obvious what that sequence of characters accomplishes.

Comment: It's not obvious what `0<&-` is meant to do. I found [this link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) which explains it.

Comment: I'm not sure what `0<&-` is either. It's very odd and something I've never seen before. Normally a file descriptor would be closed via something like `5>&-`. So this appears to be closing fd0 but it may be a typo.

Comment: That's correct, `0<&-` closes stdin (fd 0).  That way, if your process accidentally reads from stdin (easy to do), it will get an error instead of hanging forever waiting for data to show up.

Comment: And again - you need also execute "disown".

Comment: nohup redirects stdin from /dev/null automatically (see manual). Closing std file descriptors isn't the best practice.

Comment: I've found in many instances you need to also `disown $!` to prevent the interactive shell closing (on logout or parent script exit) from sending a signal to the nohup process and killing it.

Answer (score 92):

Some of the top-upvoted answers here are missing some important parts of what makes a daemon a daemon, as opposed to just a background process, or a background process detached from a shell.

This http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/ describes what is necessary to be a daemon. And this [Run bash script as daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233529/run-bash-script-as-daemon) implements the setsid, though it misses the chdir to root.

The original poster's question was actually more specific than "How do I create a daemon process using bash?", but since the subject and answers discuss daemonizing shell scripts generally, I think it's important to point it out (for interlopers like me looking into the fine details of creating a daemon).

Here's my rendition of a shell script that would behave according to the FAQ. Set DEBUG to `true` to see pretty output (but it also exits immediately rather than looping endlessly):

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBUG=false

# This part is for fun, if you consider shell scripts fun- and I do.
trap process_USR1 SIGUSR1

process_USR1() {
    echo 'Got signal USR1'
    echo 'Did you notice that the signal was acted upon only after the sleep was done'
    echo 'in the while loop? Interesting, yes? Yes.'
    exit 0
}
# End of fun. Now on to the business end of things.

print_debug() {
    whatiam="$1"; tty="$2"
    [[ "$tty" != "not a tty" ]] && {
        echo "" >$tty
        echo "$whatiam, PID $$" >$tty
        ps -o pid,sess,pgid -p $$ >$tty
        tty >$tty
    }
}

me_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
me_FILE=$(basename $0)
cd /

#### CHILD HERE --------------------------------------------------------------------->
if [ "$1" = "child" ] ; then   # 2. We are the child. We need to fork again.
    shift; tty="$1"; shift
    $DEBUG && print_debug "*** CHILD, NEW SESSION, NEW PGID" "$tty"
    umask 0
    $me_DIR/$me_FILE XXrefork_daemonXX "$tty" "$@" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
    $DEBUG && [[ "$tty" != "not a tty" ]] && echo "CHILD OUT" >$tty
    exit 0
fi

##### ENTRY POINT HERE -------------------------------------------------------------->
if [ "$1" != "XXrefork_daemonXX" ] ; then # 1. This is where the original call starts.
    tty=$(tty)
    $DEBUG && print_debug "*** PARENT" "$tty"
    setsid $me_DIR/$me_FILE child "$tty" "$@" &
    $DEBUG && [[ "$tty" != "not a tty" ]] && echo "PARENT OUT" >$tty
    exit 0
fi

##### RUNS AFTER CHILD FORKS (actually, on Linux, clone()s. See strace -------------->
                               # 3. We have been reforked. Go to work.
exec >/tmp/outfile
exec 2>/tmp/errfile
exec 0</dev/null

shift; tty="$1"; shift

$DEBUG && print_debug "*** DAEMON" "$tty"
                               # The real stuff goes here. To exit, see fun (above)
$DEBUG && [[ "$tty" != "not a tty" ]]  && echo NOT A REAL DAEMON. NOT RUNNING WHILE LOOP. >$tty

$DEBUG || {
while true; do
    echo "Change this loop, so this silly no-op goes away." >/dev/null
    echo "Do something useful with your life, young padawan." >/dev/null
    sleep 10
done
}

$DEBUG && [[ "$tty" != "not a tty" ]] && sleep 3 && echo "DAEMON OUT" >$tty

exit # This may never run. Why is it here then? It's pretty.
     # Kind of like, "The End" at the end of a movie that you
     # already know is over. It's always nice.
```

Output looks like this when `DEBUG` is set to `true`. Notice how the session and process group ID (SESS, PGID) numbers change:

```
<shell_prompt>$ bash blahd

*** PARENT, PID 5180
  PID  SESS  PGID
 5180  1708  5180
/dev/pts/6
PARENT OUT
<shell_prompt>$ 
*** CHILD, NEW SESSION, NEW PGID, PID 5188
  PID  SESS  PGID
 5188  5188  5188
not a tty
CHILD OUT

*** DAEMON, PID 5198
  PID  SESS  PGID
 5198  5188  5188
not a tty
NOT A REAL DAEMON. NOT RUNNING WHILE LOOP.
DAEMON OUT
```

Comment: It is a very nice answer! Do you (Mike S) have any kind of online presence besides SO (blog, social network, whatsoever?) I did not see anything like this on your profile information.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Not much formally. I'm afraid I'm not that interesting; I don't blog much. I own the schwager.com domain (which has little at the moment), and I do have some Arduino projects. My nom de plume is GreyGnome, generally. You can Google GreyGnome or GreyGnome + Arduino and find me around.

Comment: @MikeS Thanks! I am asking because it is not so common to meet people genuinely interested in shell programming, and I am always happy to exchanges ideas and views about this. Thank you for that complementary information! :)

Comment: @MikeS, why do you need to fork two times? In your code grandchild of the parent script becomes a new session leader with setsid, yes? Why can't you just do this for the first fork?

Comment: From the FAQ I referenced in my posting: "Here are the steps to become a daemon: ... 1. `fork()' so the parent can exit, this returns control to the command line or shell invoking your program. ... 2. `setsid()' to become a process group and session group leader  ... our process now has no controlling terminal, which is a Good Thing for daemons... 3. `fork()' again so the parent ... can exit. This means that we, as a non-session group leader, can never regain a controlling terminal."

Comment: @MikeS, so according to the FAQ:
fork -> setsid -> fork again.
In your code:
1) command &
2) setsid command &
Doesn't this set session id AFTER the second fork? IMO it should be:
1) command &
2) setsid
3) command &

Comment: @promaty You're right. I have remade the script. As a matter of fact, when one puts the ampersand at the end of the setsid line, it will fork first and then setsid- meeting the definition of the FAQ. BTW, strace shows that Linux doesn't fork, it clone()s. But the PID, PGID, and SESS variables change in accordance with the FAQ. So I think the mechanism is the same.

Comment: I'm trying to write a proper systemd file for you daemon, maybe you could help me? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460321/264975

Comment: Excelent, short, quick and clear! Thanks a lot @MikeS

Answer (score 68):

```
# double background your script to have it detach from the tty
# cf. http://www.linux-mag.com/id/5981 
(./program.sh &) &
```

Comment: Cool trick!  I usually go with no nohup, but I'll definitely find use for this one.

Comment: Great! I don't know if it's the proper way, but it works like a charm.

Comment: That doesn't seem to disconnect `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. At least not with `sh`.

Comment: This has the added benefit of reparenting the process to init, which was what I was looking for in order to avoid zombies if the script running this later execs.

Comment: This method for detaching is used quite a bit. It's called the "double fork" and is explained in more depth in one of the holy UNIX scriptures, 2nd Stevens (http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201433079).

Comment: -1 This does not detach from the tty. As a test, create a file `~/doit.sh`: `for i in seq 1 2 3 4 5; do echo Hello $i; sleep 1; done` . Now run it: `(/bin/bash ~/doit.sh &) &` . It will happily echo to your tty. Furthermore, the linux magazine article doesn't even cover the detaching from tty part. Strangely, they have a link to the FAQ but ignore the stuff that makes a daemon a daemon (as opposed to a process started in the background), then confusingly call it a daemon. Even more strange, they start out ok and even call their script "daemon-like" but then they run off the rails.

Comment: For more technical information about the double fork and setsid(), see http://thelinuxjedi.blogspot.com/2014/02/why-use-double-fork-to-daemonize.html . Especially read the section "The breakdown", where it says, "The real steps behind the double-fork are as follows:"

Comment: You have to execute "disown" to make started process a real daemon.

Comment: Trying above from the commandline shows that while it gets a new process group leader, it retains the session leader id until the original session (ie: commandline) exits, removing the rest of the session processes (except program.sh).

Answer (score 5):

`$ ( cd /; umask 0; setsid your_script.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null & ) &`

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what is the binary itself going to do.

For example I want to create some listener.

The starting Daemon is simple task :

lis_deamon :

```
#!/bin/bash

# We will start the listener as Deamon process
#    
LISTENER_BIN=/tmp/deamon_test/listener
test -x $LISTENER_BIN || exit 5
PIDFILE=/tmp/deamon_test/listener.pid

case "$1" in
      start)
            echo -n "Starting Listener Deamon .... "
            startproc -f -p $PIDFILE $LISTENER_BIN
            echo "running"
            ;;
          *)
            echo "Usage: $0 start"
            exit 1
            ;;
esac
```

this is how we start the daemon (common way for all /etc/init.d/ staff)

now as for the listener it self,
It must be some kind of loop/alert or else that will trigger the script 
to do what u want. For example if u want your script to sleep 10 min
and wake up and ask you how you are doing u will do this with the

```
while true ; do sleep 600 ; echo "How are u ? " ; done
```

Here is the simple listener that u can do that will listen for your 
commands from remote machine and execute them on local :

listener :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Starting listener on some port
# we will run it as deamon and we will send commands to it.
#
IP=$(hostname --ip-address)
PORT=1024
FILE=/tmp/backpipe
count=0
while [ -a $FILE ] ; do #If file exis I assume that it used by other program
  FILE=$FILE.$count
  count=$(($count + 1))
done

# Now we know that such file do not exist,
# U can write down in deamon it self the remove for those files
# or in different part of program

mknod $FILE p

while true ; do 
  netcat -l -s $IP -p $PORT < $FILE |/bin/bash > $FILE
done
rm $FILE
```

So to start UP it : /tmp/deamon_test/listener start

and to send commands from shell (or wrap it to script) :

```
test_host#netcat 10.184.200.22 1024
uptime
 20:01pm  up 21 days  5:10,  44 users,  load average: 0.62, 0.61, 0.60
date
Tue Jan 28 20:02:00 IST 2014
 punt! (Cntrl+C)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the daemon tool from the libslack package:

http://ingvar.blog.linpro.no/2009/05/18/todays-sysadmin-tip-using-libslack-daemon-to-daemonize-a-script/

On Mac OS X use a launchd script for shell daemon.

Answer (score 1):

If I had a `script.sh` and i wanted to execute it from bash and leave it running even when I want to close my bash session then I would combine `nohup` and `&` at the end.

example: `nohup ./script.sh < inputFile.txt > ./logFile 2>&1 &`

`inputFile.txt` can be any file. If your file has no input then we usually use `/dev/null`. So the command would be:

`nohup ./script.sh < /dev/null > ./logFile 2>&1 &`

After that close your bash session,open another terminal and execute: `ps -aux | egrep "script.sh"` and you will see that your script is still running at the background. Of cource,if you want to stop it then execute the same command (ps) and `kill -9 <PID-OF-YOUR-SCRIPT>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the minimal change to the original proposal to create a valid daemon in Bourne shell (or Bash):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" != "__forked__" ]; then
    setsid "$0" __forked__ "$@" &
    exit
else
    shift
fi

trap 'siguser1=true' SIGUSR1
trap 'echo "Clean up and exit"; kill $sleep_pid; exit' SIGTERM
exec > outfile
exec 2> errfile
exec 0< /dev/null

while true; do
    (sleep 30000000 &>/dev/null) &
    sleep_pid=$!
    wait
    kill $sleep_pid &>/dev/null
    if [ -n "$siguser1" ]; then
        siguser1=''
        echo "Wait was interrupted by SIGUSR1, do things here."
    fi
done
```

Explanation:

- Line 2-7: A daemon must be forked so it doesn't have a parent. Using an artificial argument to prevent endless forking. "setsid" detaches from starting process and terminal.
- Line 9: Our desired signal needs to be differentiated from other signals.
- Line 10: Cleanup is required to get rid of dangling "sleep" processes.
- Line 11-13: Redirect stdout, stderr and stdin of the script.
- Line 16: sleep in the background
- Line 18: wait waits for end of sleep, but gets interrupted by (some) signals.
- Line 19: Kill sleep process, because that is still running when signal is caught.
- Line 22: Do the work if SIGUSR1 has been caught.

Guess it does not get any simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

See **Bash Service Manager** project: https://github.com/reduardo7/bash-service-manager

### Implementation example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PID_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.pid"
export LOG_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.log"
export LOG_ERROR_FILE_PATH="/tmp/my-service.error.log"

. ./services.sh

run-script() {
  local action="$1" # Action

  while true; do
    echo "@@@ Running action '${action}'"
    echo foo
    echo bar >&2

    [ "$action" = "run" ] && return 0
    sleep 5
    [ "$action" = "debug" ] && exit 25
  done
}

before-start() {
  local action="$1" # Action

  echo "* Starting with $action"
}

after-finish() {
  local action="$1" # Action
  local serviceExitCode=$2 # Service exit code

  echo "* Finish with $action. Exit code: $serviceExitCode"
}

action="$1"
serviceName="Example Service"

serviceMenu "$action" "$serviceName" run-script "$workDir" before-start after-finish
```

### Usage example

```
$ ./example-service
# Actions: [start|stop|restart|status|run|debug|tail(-[log|error])]

$ ./example-service start
# Starting Example Service service...

$ ./example-service status
# Serive Example Service is runnig with PID 5599

$ ./example-service stop
# Stopping Example Service...

$ ./example-service status
# Service Example Service is not running
```

Answer (score 0):

[Congbin Duo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49183740/2580621) mostly gets the right elements to properly daemonize a process, including double forking, detaching stdin/stdout/stderr, resetting the cwd and umask, and running setsid. However, it has two issues:

- It has a race condition where if the terminal quickly exits after his one-liner, the to-daemonize process will never actually run. For example, the following command will reliably *not* execute the `sleep` command (for reference, tested on a Fedora Workstation 38 v1.6 LiveCD):

  ```bash
  gnome-terminal -- sh -c '( cd /; umask 0; setsid sleep 123 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & ) &'
  ```

  As far as I can tell, the problem is that if the terminal exits before the process has been fully daemonized (i.e. `setsid` has exec'd the command), this will break the daemonized process and the command will never actually run.
- The double fork and `setsid` sequence is not done in the right order. It should be done like `fork; setsid; fork;` instead of `fork; fork; setsid;`. See for example "[UNIX daemonization and the double fork](https://0xjet.github.io/3OHA/2022/04/11/post.html)" for a more detailed explanation.

The following one-liner, to my best knowledge, fixes those issues:

```
setsid sh -c 'cd /; umask 0; "$@" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &' -- your-script.sh arg1 arg2 & wait $!
```

Explanation:

1. `[...] & wait $!` is the first `fork()`. We wait for it to avoid exiting prematurely and breaking the daemonization process.
2. `setsid [...]` is the call to `setsid()`.
3. `sh -c '[...] &' -- your-script.sh arg1 arg2` starts a shell to do the second `fork()` inside it.

   `your-script.sh arg1 arg2` is the script to daemonize and its arguments (you do not need to escape them) and will be stored in the `$@` variable.
4. `cd /; umask 0; "$@" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` does the rest of the daemonization (reset cwd and umask, detach stdin/stdout/stderr) and then invokes the daemon.

Answer (score -1):

Like many answers this one is not a "real" daemonization but rather an alternative to `nohup` approach.

```
echo "script.sh" | at now
```

There are obviously differences from using `nohup`. For one there is no detaching from the parent in the first place. Also "script.sh" doesn't inherit parent's environment.

By no means this is a better alternative. It is simply a different (and somewhat lazy) way of launching processes in background.

P.S. I personally upvoted carlo's answer as it seems to be the most elegant and works both from terminal and inside scripts

Answer (score -4):

try executing using &
if you save this file as program.sh

you can use

```
$. program.sh &
```