# Running a command in a specific terminal using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Assuming there are are no processes running in a specific terminal (say pts/1), is it possible to run a command in that terminal from a shell script which is running in another terminal?

Please guide.

Thanks in advance,
Saeya

Comment: are terminals hardwired ? so you want the output of your program to go to another terminal , right ?

Comment: No, I do not want the output of a program in another terminal. Rather I want the process to start a command's execution in the other terminal. That command should run independently in the other terminal. It should look as though the command was given in that terminal.

Comment: how about running a shell script to wait for an event ( eg : a file trigger) and start the process ?

Comment: If you don't care about output, why do you care which terminal process spawns the worker? Just run the script as a background process, independent of the terminal(s) entirely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274622/run-script-in-background