# Run bash script as daemon

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, daemons

I have a script, which runs my PHP script each X times:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
/usr/bin/php -f ./my-script.php
echo "Waiting..."
sleep 3
done
```

How can I start it as daemon?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To run it as a full daemon from a shell, you'll need to use `setsid` and redirect its output. You can redirect the output to a logfile, or to `/dev/null` to discard it. Assuming your script is called myscript.sh, use the following command:

```
setsid myscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

This will completely detach the process from your current shell (stdin, stdout and stderr). If you want to keep the output in a logfile, replace the first `/dev/null` with your /path/to/logfile.

You have to redirect the output, otherwise it will not run as a true daemon (it will depend on your shell to read and write output).

Comment: how do I kill it then?

Comment: You'll have to find it's pid and send it a signal. Here's an UNSAFE example for linux systems: `kill $(ps -fade | grep myscript.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`. This will kill all processes which contain "myscript.sh" in their name or parameters so it's not very safe to use, but you can tweak it to suite your needs.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! Can you please explain what `2>&1 < /dev/null` is doing?

Comment: @DanielPatrick in bash (and most other shells) this is stdin/stderr/stdout redirection. The `> /dev/null` (same as `1>/dev/null`) redirects stdout (which is file descriptor 1) to /dev/null. The `2>&1` means redirect all stderr (file descriptor 2) to file descriptor 1, which is already redirected to /dev/null. The `</dev/null` attaches /dev/null to stdin (fd 0). All of these let the script detach from all current input/output sources, and reattach to /dev/null. Hope this answers.

Comment: Very helpful, was familiar with redirection but not with the file descriptors.  Thank you!

Comment: (in BASH) find it with $ pgrep -l <your process name>

Comment: (in BASH) kill it with $ pkill <your process name>

Comment: So far this is the only one that works for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 44):

A Daemon is just program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user...

[The below bash code is for Debian systems - Ubuntu, Linux Mint distros and so on]

**The simple way:**

The simple way would be to edit your /etc/rc.local file and then just have your script run from there (i.e. everytime you boot up the system):

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following and save:

```
#For a BASH script
/bin/sh TheNameOfYourScript.sh > /dev/null &
```

**The better way to do this would be to create a Daemon via Upstart:**

```
sudo nano /etc/init/TheNameOfYourDaemon.conf
```

add the following:

```
description "My Daemon Job"
author "Your Name"
start on runlevel [2345]    

pre-start script
  echo "[`date`] My Daemon Starting" >> /var/log/TheNameOfYourDaemonJobLog.log
end script

exec /bin/sh TheNameOfYourScript.sh > /dev/null &
```

Save this.

Confirm that it looks ok:

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/TheNameOfYourDaemon.conf
```

Now reboot the machine:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now when you boot up your system, you can see the log file stating that your Daemon is running:

```
cat  /var/log/TheNameOfYourDaemonJobLog.log
```

• Now you may start/stop/restart/get the status of your Daemon via:

*restart: this will stop, then start a service*

```
sudo service TheNameOfYourDaemonrestart restart
```

*start: this will start a service, if it's not running*

```
sudo service TheNameOfYourDaemonstart start
```

*stop: this will stop a service, if it's running*

```
sudo service TheNameOfYourDaemonstop stop
```

*status: this will display the status of a service*

```
sudo service TheNameOfYourDaemonstatus status
```

Comment: You should really indicate the distro this is for, because these commands and paths are not correct on all distros.

Comment: Good point sgtPooki. I added a caveat explaining that my example refers to Ubuntu / Mint distributions etc. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: Could someone do a systemd add-on to this answer? :)

Comment: Note that Upstart is deprecated. Ubuntu moved to systemd.

Answer (score 15):

You can go to /etc/init.d/ - you will see a daemon template called skeleton.

You can duplicate it and then enter your script under the start function.

Comment: you may also consider running the script in background by adding '&' at the end or running it with nohup.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz how can I make it run in the background automatically. for instance when you issue /etc/init.d/mysql start, the daemon starts and runs in the background by default.

Comment: @DavidOkwii put your code in a function and run it in the background. Check my answer added to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Another cool trick is to run functions or subshells in background, not always feasible though

```
name(){
  echo "Do something"
  sleep 1
}

# put a function in the background
name &
#Example taken from here
#https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Putting_functions_in_background
```

Running a subshell in the background

```
(echo "started"; sleep 15; echo "stopped") &
```

Answer (score 0):

Some commentors already stated that answers to your question will not work for all distributions. Since you did not include CentOS in the question but only in the tags, I'd like to post here the topics one has to understand in order to have a control over his/her proceeding regardless of the distribution:

1. what is the init daemon (optional)
2. what is the inittab file (/etc/inittab)
3. what does the inittab file do in your distro (e.g. does it actually run all
   scripts in /etc/init.d ?)

For your problem, one could start the script on sysinit by adding this line in /etc/inittab and make it respawn in case it terminates:

```
# start and respawn after termination
ttyS0::respawn:/bin/sh /path/to/my_script.sh
```

The script has to be made executable in advance of course:

```
chmod +x /path/to/my_script.sh
```

Hope this helps