# Bash: How to get a script to rerun itself as a background task?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I'm writing a Bash script that is intended to be used as a daemon. If the user of my script does not pass a `--sync` option to the script, I want the script to rerun itself as a background task using that option. Here is my code (the last part was stolen from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908325/4077294)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=("$@") # capture them here so we can use them if --sync's not passed
async=true

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
        --sync)
            async=false
            ;;
        # other options
    esac
    shift
done

# if --sync isn't passed, rerun the script as a background task
$async && exec nohup "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" --sync "${args[@]}" 0<&- &> /dev/null &
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be working. When I do `bash -x myscript` (which helps debug the script), it seems that it just keeps on going even if `$async` is true, which I didn't think would happen since `exec` normally stops execution.

Likewise, if I run this command from my terminal:

```
exec nohup true 0<&- &> /dev/null &
```

it also fails to exit the shell, despite the use of `exec`. Why is this, and what can I do to work around it? (Bonus points: Is there any way to do this **without** creating a subshell?)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use _jobs/bg_ command to switch itself to backgroud.

Comment: @gzh Sounds great! Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` is being applied to the `exec` command itself, so `exec foo &` forks a new asynchronous subshell (or equivalent thereto, see below). That subshell immediately replaces itself with `foo`. If you want the parent (that is, your script) to terminate as well, you'll need to do so explicitly with an `exit` command.

The `exec` is probably not buying you anything here. Bash is clever enough to not actually start a subshell for a simple backgrounded command. So it should be sufficient to do:

```
if $async; then
  nohup "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" --sync "${args[@]}" 0<&- &> /dev/null &
  exit 0
fi
```

I don't know of a way to do this without a subshell. But when you write shell scripts, you get subshells. Personally I'd just use a simple variable and test it with something like `if [[ $async ]];` instead of executing `true` or `false`, but since those are also bash builtins, it's pretty well equivalent. In other shells they might run in subshells.

Now that I think of it, since you're reprocessing all the options in async execution anyway, you might as well just fork and exit from within the `case` statement, so you don't need the second check at all:

```
case "$1" in
    --sync)
        nohup "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" --sync "${args[@]}" 0<&- &> /dev/null &
        exit 0
        ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with rici's answer because the question clearly states background-ing is only wanted when --sync is NOT passed into the script.  What was shown appears to be an infinite loop, and isn't checking all the parameters passed.  I believe the original code was fine, except for the final "async && exec ...".  The following replacement for that line should work:

```
if [ "$async" = true ]; then
   nohup "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" --sync "${args[@]}" 0<&- &> /dev/null &
   exit 0
fi
```

followed by what your code is supposed to do when --sync is passed.