# How to execute a shell script when a file changes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, service

In my directory, I have a text file called `test.txt` and I have a shell script called `targetscript.sh`.

I want to run this shell script when any changes occur on test.file. On my server, I have no option to install new tools like `inotfy` or similar like anything.

So after some research I wrote the following shell script which will take the time stamp of test.txt and if any changes occur it will trigger the `targetscript.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    ATIME=$(stat -c %Z /home/haider/test.txt)
    if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]; then
        echo "RUN COMMNAD"
        ./targetscript.sh
        LTIME=$ATIME
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

But I am getting the following error.
[image]

Comment: `%(` should be `$(`

Comment: @0stone0 i have typed wrong i used $(....)...any other suggestion plz

Comment: The error suggests that you're missing a blank after `[[` in your actual script, unlike in the one you're showing us.

Comment: Then there's probably a space missing on `if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]; then`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and **copy&paste** the code, commands and error messages **as text** to the question. Don't show a screenshot of text. Don't retype the code in the question because this way you may hide or introduce errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `[[1617030570: command not found` error is caused by a missing space after the `[[` (**Not shown in question**)

Secondly, you'll always run `./targetscript.sh` on the first iteration since `LTIME` isn't set. Therefore the `"$ATIME" != "$LTIME"` will fail, and the `sh` script will be executed.

Consider setting `$LTIME` before the while-loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
LTIME=$(stat -c %Z /private/tmp/jq/tst.txt)
while true
do
  ATIME=$(stat -c %Z /private/tmp/jq/tst.txt)
  if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]; then
        echo "RUN COMMNAD"
        ./targetscript.sh
        LTIME=$ATIME
  fi
  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Thanks, @0stone0.  I have another question...if I close the putty window/exit the server it stopped the monitorScript automatically...but I want the monitor script will work 24/7 and look for changes...then what modification/measure I need to take

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Regarding the second question, that out-of-scope of the current question. However, you'll need to run the script in the background, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/best-way-to-make-a-shell-script-daemon) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426862/proper-way-to-run-shell-script-as-a-daemon) to get started!

Comment: When trying to execute this "./targetscript.sh" I am getting this error . no such file or directory... any more suggestion @0stone0

Comment: The dot (`.`) means 'current dir', are you sure the file exist? Again, please keep on the current question scope, any other questions can be asked on a new one

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try the `entr` command. This command is not on a mac by default and if you are using mac, you need to install it by homebrew.

```
brew install entr
```

If you are using Linux, you can install it by apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install entr
```

### How to use `entr`?

You first list out the files that you are watching, then pipe the list into the `entr` command. Basically, if you have a `example.txt` file and you want to monitor it and execute a command whenever it is changed, use this command.

```
ls example.txt | entr echo "watching..."
```

Another basic usage is that you first define your bash script and make it executable, then run this command.

```
find . -type f | entr "./run.sh"
```

`find . -type f` returns a list of files inside the current directory recursively. The result is then pipe into the `entr` command, executing the script `run.sh`.